# How to get the date when accumulation (sum) in a condition in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, sum

I have table like this:

| id | date | total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2021-02-03 | 200000 |
| 123 | 2021-03-03 | 1650000 |
| 123 | 2021-02-04 | 1500000 |
| 123 | 2021-02-21 | 200000 |
| 123 | 2021-03-03 | 200000 |

How's the sql query if I want to get the date when sum of total reach 3000000 or when the date on 2021-02-04?

the expected output is

| id | date | total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2021-02-04 | 3350000 |

or if not possible maybe like this:

| id | date |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 2021-02-04 |

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and also add the expected output (based on your sample data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
select top 1 * from (
select id,date,
SUM(total) OVER (ORDER BY date ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) as Total 
from tablename
)
where total >= 3000000
```

Comment: i am sorry, i have edited the question, maybe you can adjust again. Thank you. When I put this to case when, i got the date before reach 300000, but what i want is the date when reach 3000000

Comment: you can add where condition like `whare date <= 2021-02-04`.

Comment: still can not get the date, and actually the whole table have many id and different date of course which make different date where reach 3000000

Comment: with your code I get 2021-03-03 not 2021-02-04

Comment: `<=` is come with 2021-02-04. But it's sample data your logic not sore what you want. i think different way to get data in your case.

Comment: @Erik Now check Only One Row Return you want it.